# Update by query not working, elastic search python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have about 2000+ documents with the file name 'Contact.txt', I am trying to amend a field called `text: {class: 'contact'}` for all of these files, by doing the following:

```
    q = {
        "script": {
            "inline": "ctx._source.text.class='contact'",
            "lang": "painless"
        },
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "name": "Contact.txt"
            },

        }
    }

    try:
        es.update_by_query(body=q, index='index_name')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

My try/catch is giving me the error:

```
TransportError(500, 'script_exception', 'runtime error')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text` field doesn't exist in the documents so, the update script should be as below:

```
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source['text'] = params.text",
    "params": {
      "text": {
        "class": "contact"
      }
    },
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "Contact.txt"
    }
  }
}
```